# How far apart are Azure Availability Zones located?

Tags: azure

Microsoft says their regions are located 300 Miles apart but there is no documentation on how far their Availability Zones are located.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/reliability/cross-region-replication-azure

How far are the Azure Zones located?

Comment: The exact distance between datacenters within a region is not publicly disclosed by Microsoft for security reasons.

Comment: `Microsoft says their regions are located 300 Miles apart` - they don't. They say they "strive" to do that, but that it isn't always possible.

Answer (score 1):

"Azure availability zones are connected by a high-performance network with a round-trip latency of less than 2ms."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/reliability/availability-zones-overview#availability-zones

Comment: https://www.itpro.com/infrastructure/data-centres/google-cloud-deep-into-second-day-of-fire-and-flood-data-center-fiasco

So many of you might know that recently google’s data center went down and that seems like a bad design. Its not confirmed yet but looks like they had zone a,b and c located on same site.

I was just curious on how Microsoft handle this via their availability zones. As there is no documentation shared anywhere which clearly states any meaningful information on how far each zone is located.

Comment: @HappyChampanary if you wanted to know what the minimum distance is... that was not your question.

Comment: apologies for confusion, but yes I wanted to know the how far their Availability Zones are located.